# What is the difference between "get my hair cut" or "have my hair cut"

Tags: meaning

> 1. I **have** my hair cut.
> 2. I **get** my hair cut.

What is the difference between the two sentences in meaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both sentences mean that the speaker does not cut his own hair, but has another person do it.

The pattern

{someone}   gets|has + {something} + {past participle of a transitive verb} {optional phrase identifying the entity who does the deed}

**I get|have my car fixed at that garage.**

**He gets|has the newspaper delivered.**

**The unwary king neglects to get|have his food tasted.**

**The politician got|had his TV commercial aired at prime time in ten major media markets.**

**Get** is felt to be informal.

Comment: But what is the difference between "get" and "have", if any?

Comment: I was typing an addendum as you were typing.

Comment: Non-native opinion: the use of "have" in that phrase sounds more like atemporal, while "get" can be more suited for actions, like "I'm going to get a haircut" or "I got my hair cut last week".

Comment: I had my hair cut last week. I got my hair cut last week.  She's having her ears pierced tomorrow. She's getting her ears pierced tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Although *have* and *get* are often used interchangeably in the causative, *get* is somewhat stronger than *have* (it contains a stronger idea of action by the subject). For example:

> I must get my car serviced soon.
>
> Finally, I got my roof repaired

.
In these examples, there is also a suggestion of some difficulty, which would not be conveyed by *had*.

Besides, *get* sounds more natural than *have* in the imperative:

> Get your hair cut.
>   Get your eyes tested.

And lastly, in suggestions like "why don't you", *get* is much stronger than *have*:

> Why don t you have your hair cut? (Neutral suggestion)
>
> Why don t you get your hair cut? (Almost an order)

Answer (score 2):

I would add to @TRomano's answer that Get feels more American, while most British would choose to say Have. 
The above was definitely true some years (well, decades) ago but has changed a lot since then (and still changing)...

Comment: @user3169 There is no present perfect in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Since the actions in a "haircut" are not a moment in time, I would use present perfect:

> I **am having** my hair cut.

or

> I **am getting** my hair cut.

In AmE I prefer using "get". "have" reads more like a special occasion/occurrence , not something done routinely or because it is basically required for some reason.

> I **am having** my birthday party on Saturday.
>   I **am getting** my car repaired on Monday.